# Why is OWASP CSRF-guard falsely detecting an attack when a user simply navigates to any page in my web-app?

Tags: java, csrf, configuration, owasp

I'm trying to use OWASP's CSRFGuard in my Java Spring-MVC web-app but it's detecting a CSRF attack for any action a user makes. The web-app loads and as soon as the user tries to navigate to any section of the web-app the org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Log.Message I have set-up in the
CSRFguard.properties file reports "error: required token is missing from the request". Even though the URL does contain a token (see screenshot)?

[image: OWASP CSRF-Guard false-positive issue]

Here is my `Owasp.CsrfGuard.properties` file:

```
org.owasp.csrfguard.Logger=org.owasp.csrfguard.log.ConsoleLogger
org.owasp.csrfguard.configuration.provider.factory = org.owasp.csrfguard.config.overlay.ConfigurationAutodetectProviderFactory
org.owasp.csrfguard.Enabled = true
org.owasp.csrfguard.ValidateWhenNoSessionExists = false
org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenPerPage=false
org.owasp.csrfguard.Rotate=false
org.owasp.csrfguard.Ajax=true
org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Log=org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Log
org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Log.Message=potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:%user%, ip:%remote_ip%, method:%request_method%, uri:%request_uri%, error:%exception_message%)
org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Redirect=org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Redirect
org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Redirect.Page=%servletContext%/error.jsp
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.Css=*.css
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.JavaScript=*.js
org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenName=csrfToken
org.owasp.csrfguard.SessionKey=csrfToken
org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenLength=32
org.owasp.csrfguard.PRNG=SHA1PRNG
org.owasp.csrfguard.PRNG.Provider=SUN
org.owasp.csrfguard.Config.Print = true
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.sourceFile =  WEB-INF/csrfguard.js
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.domainStrict = true
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.cacheControl = private, maxage=28800
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.injectIntoForms = true
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.injectGetForms = true
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.injectFormAttributes = true
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.injectIntoAttributes = true 
org.owasp.csrfguard.configOverlay.secondsBetweenUpdateChecks = 60
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is OWASP CSRF-guard falsely detecting an attack when a user simply navigates to any page in web-app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527467/why-is-owasp-csrf-guard-falsely-detecting-an-attack-when-a-user-simply-navigates)

Comment: Can you provide the log output?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the tokens are not passed with the http request. I would recommend using tamper data to verify that tokens are being sent with the http request. There might be a jsp or an html involved that is directing requests to the specific pages and you need to inject token there.
If you have already tried the dynamic javascript injection then you can try JSP tag library injection because sometimes dynamic javascript injection doesn't work.

[csrfguard 3.1.0 example](https://github.com/aramrami/OWASP-CSRFGuard)

[csrfguard token injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRFGuard_3_Token_Injection)